# Как получить разделение на категории?

Tags: php, mysql

В базе есть записи с валютами, и у каждой валюты своя категория. Валюта и категория в одной таблице.

Структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где - **code** и есть категория.

В таблице записи в таком виде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывожу все так:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `valuta` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
while ($item= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   ?>
     <option><?=$item['name'];?></option>
   <?
}
```

Хочу получить вот такую разметку:

```
<optgroup label="RUB">
 //option
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="USD">
 //option
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="BTC">
 //option
</optgroup>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая вашу задачу, мне кажется будет правильнее сгруппировать массив данных и им уже оперировать в дальнейшем.

```
$myArray = [];

while ($item= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   $myArray[$item['code']][] = $item;
}

foreach ($myArray as &key => $value): ?>

<optgroup label="<?= $key; ?>">

    <? foreach($value as $v): ?>

        <option value="<?= $v['name']; ?>">
            <?= $v['name']; ?>
        </option>

    <? endforeach; ?>

</optgroup>

<? endforeach;
```